# Android String Parsing

Tags: android, parsing, bluetooth

I am writing an android app that recieves data over bluetooth. The bytes comming in can be of any size example: 00023>024935928598235>9284>

As you can see each set is seperated by ">". The data comes in extremely fast. I would like some ideas for an implementation. See my problem is that I need to read the data into a byte array that can and then convert it to a string and split them according to the delimeter of ">".

so in the above example:

00023
024935928598235
9284

If i set byte[] data = new byte[8] then when reading the incomming data it might get 00023>02 which is not what i want. I'm not sure how to implement something like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach. You'll have to implement the readDataFromBluetooth() and somehow set dataAvailable, but this should get you on the right track.

```
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    List<String> chunks = new LinkedList<String>();
    StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();

    while (dataAvailable) {
        data = readDataFromBluetooth();

        for (byte b : data) {
            if (b == '<') {
                chunks.add(chunk.toString());
                chunk.setLength(0);
            } else {
                chunk.append(b);
            }
        }
    }

    if (chunk.length() > 0)
        chunks.add(chunk.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a buffered stream, but maybe a bit bigger that 8 bytes, as you suggest, and the read one and one character from the beginning of the stream, accumulating the string. When you encounter a ">", send the value you have accumulated off to a queue for a background thread processing. Use standard producer/consumer implementation techniques (e.g. the Monitor pattern) to communicate via the queue.